# Reading Discrete Inputs from Fatek FBs PLC using C#

Tags: c#, tcp, plc, modbus-tcp

I have a Fatek Fbs PLC, Discrete inputs are connected to X0(001001) register. I want To read those input values through C#. I tried EasymodbusTCP library but It is not working.

```
ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("190.201.100.100", 502);    modbusClient.Connect(); 
bool[] readCoils = modbusClient.ReadCoils(0,10);
int[] readHoldingRegisters = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0,10);
string val=modbusClient.ReadDiscreteInputs(0,1)[0].ToString());  //this line throws exception
```

Comment: Why not show your EasymodbusTCP code and describe in what way it isn't working? I'm not familiar with this area, but I'm sure others are and would be able to help you fix the code you already have.

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: @John " Starting Address Invalid or starting address+quantity is invalid"

Comment: Why did you just delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685025/merge-comma-separated-string-c-sharp ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use faconServer

1. Download and install FaconServer (fatek communication server) from Fatek website.
2. Run FaconServer as administrator ( this is necessary )
3. Create a new project with FaconServer and add a list of your register that you want to read or write and save it to your application project folder
4. Add FaconServer library to your project using "add reference"
5. In your code create an object of PLC and read register's data or write like this :

```
// create an object of your PLC
FaconSvr.FaconServer faconServer = new FaconSvr.FaconServer();
faconServer.OpenProject(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\FcnSvr.fcs");
faconServer.Connect();

// to reading  Register 'R100' from PLC
string Result = Convert.ToString(faconServer.GetItem("Channel0.Station0.station 01", "R100"));

// to write value : 128 in Register 'R200' on PLC
faconServer.SetItem("Channel0.Station0.Station 01", "R200", "128");
```